# sudo su doesn't change users for mysql

Tags: sudo, su

Last night, on my server, I did:

```
sudo su - mysql
```

to change to the mysql user so I could run the mysql client, which is set up so it will only authenticate from the mysql account.  I successfully ran the mysql client and made the change to the database.  Nothing changed on the server overnight.

Today, nothing I try will allow my to change to the mysql user.  It appears to succeed, given the message about no home directory, but `whoami` still reports my user id and trying to run mysql still fails.

```
wade@snoopy:~$ sudo su - mysql
[sudo] password for wade: 
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
wade@snoopy:~$ whoami
wade

wade@snoopy:~$ sudo su mysql
wade@snoopy:~$ whoami
wade

wwilliam@snoopy:~$ sudo -s
root@snoopy:/home/wade# 
root@snoopy:/home/wade# su mysql
root@snoopy:/home/wade# whoami
root
```

/etc/passwd for mysql:

```
mysql:x:110:119:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false
```

Has anyone ever seen behavior like this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`su` invokes the other user's login shell as given in  `/etc/passwd`. In your case that's `/bin/false` so you don't get any interactive shell.

Use

```
sudo -u test /bin/bash
```

or

```
sudo -u test /usr/bin/mysql
```

or something like that instead.